# Launch a process with secrets as environment variables

Tags: linux, gnupg, secrets-management, environment-variables

I have a process that needs secret keys to be passed as environment variables. That is for historical reasons.

I have a AWS machine where this process runs but I do not want to store these keys in files or scripts on the cloud.

What is the industry standard process for this situation? Do folks typically store the secret files under a username, lock it with standard unix file/user permissions, and hope for the best?

I thought about to somehow keep those secrets on a secure machine remotely and then start processes on the remote machine with the provided keys, passing them through ssh. For that I'd have to customize /etc/sshd/config to allow some of these environment variables to be passed in the environment. Is this safer?

Alternatively, I thought about starting these processes with crontab but then reach back home for the secrets.

As a third option I thought about storing these files as gpg encrypted files to be decrypted through ssh.

Am I being too stringent on my requirements?

Thank you,

Comment: Welcome to the community. Are you running bare metal, Docker, one of the Kubernetes variants, Hypervisors etc?..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AWS the best practice would probably be [Key Management Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/overview.html) for cryptographic key material, and [Secrets Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/intro.html) for other kinds of secrets, e.g. database tokens.

You'll have to decide if this is secure enough, based on a threat model you develop.

Comment: What would be the on-premises equivalent of AWS secrets management?

Comment: So I set up the AWS keys management. However when I went to use it - you have to use boto3 (in Python) and then you have to have the AWS keys configured. So it's like tying a dog with sausage.